# sum of all abundant numbers less than or equal to n

Tags: c++, optimization, mathematical-optimization

The problem is to find the sum of all abundant numbers less than or equal to n where an abundant number is a number whose sum of all proper factors is greater than that number for eg. 12 is an abundant number as
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16 which is greater than 12.

This is my implementation I am getting TLE and I'm stuck here can't seem to find any way.
Please help.

```
int isAbundant(int n){
int sum = 0;
for (int i=1; i<=sqrt(n); i++){
    if (n%i==0){
        if (n/i == i)
            sum = sum + i;

        else{
            sum = sum + i;
            sum = sum + (n / i);
        }
    }
}
if(sum - n > n) return 1;
else            return 0;
}

int find_abundant_numbers(int n1) {

set<int> s;

if(n1 < 12)  return 0;

for(int i = 12; i <= n1; i++){
    if(i % 2 != 0 && i < 945){
        continue;
    }
    if(s.find(i) == s.end()){
        int isA = isAbundant(i);
        if(isA){
            for(int j = 1; j * i <= n1; j++){
                s.insert(i * j);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        continue;
    }
    //if(isA) cout << isA << " ";
}

return accumulate(s.begin(), s.end(), 0);
}
```

Comment: If you want some help regarding the concept of abundant numbers please check out its Wikipedia article, It is a mathematical concept, and hence certain properties can be leveraged. I tried to do the same but was unable to break the time barrier.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number

Comment: I have never heard of a TLE, what is that?

Comment: @Dominique: "Time limit exceeded"/"Too long execution", it is from challenging site.

Comment: Questions about code optimisation, aren't those for the codereview.stackExchange.com website instead of here?

Comment: At which coding platform you're getting TLE, As you are not providing the constraints, so,  may you provide the link to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is to find the **set** of abundant numbers less than n, not to check if **one** particular number is abundant. Take for instance the sieve of Eratosthenes, an ancient algorithm for finding all prime numbers less than a given number. It doesn't check one by one if a number is a prime, but work more efficiently instead at a higher level, on a range of numbers.

The idea is to have an array `std::vector<int> sum(n + 1);` (initially all values are set to 0) which is incrementally filled until we obtain the desired sum of strict divisors for **all** numbers. Given a value (a divisor), the subprocess is to update the array `sum` by adding this value to all elements in `sum` representing numbers divisible by it (strictly):

```
auto propagate_divisor = [&](int divisor) {
    for (int i = 2 * divisor; i <= n; i += divisor)
        sum[i] += divisor;
};
```

And then, we do that for all possible values:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    propagate_divisor(i);
```

Now, as `sum` is built, we just have to pick the abundant numbers (here, I just print them):

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    if (sum[i] > i)
        printf("%i ", i);
```

[You can try it here.](https://godbolt.org/z/fcGqqn)